# Icons are not displayed when using KivyMD with kivy-ios

Tags: kivy, kivymd

The app starts and runs but all the icons are not being displayed.
I'm installing kivymd using toolchain like this:

`toolchain pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`

(Please note: toolchain pip install kivymd has the same issue)

I'm using

```
kivy-ios = master
kivy = b5ec51e (thats the recipe available in the toolchain)
sdl2_ttf = 2.0.14 (thats the recipe available in the toolchain)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `requirements = sdl2_ttf == 2.0.15`

Comment: But - to my understanding - the only recipe currently available for installation through the toolchain is the sdl2_ttf==2.0.14. How can make a custom recipe?

Comment: You are wrong, I made a `pull request` in `p4a` for a long time, which fixes this problem, you just need to use the `develop` branch, by default it is `master`, or explicitly specify it as in my example above

Comment: I'm talking about using kivy with kivy-ios, not with p4a.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when you run toolchain recipes it will tell you sdl2_ttf is 2.0.14 but when you actually check the file inside the build you'll see that its 2.0.15.

What I did to fix the issue is to download KivyMD 0.104.2rc3 from the master using toolchain pip install -upgrade KivyMD=master

then removed sdl2_ttf by running toolchain clean sdl2_ttf then rebuild it again.

Hopefully this will work for you :-)

Comment: Hi there - just a tip, Stackoverflow is compatible with markdown syntax. Enclosing code blocks with "\`" makes them more readable. For example, `pip install -upgrade KivyMD=master`

Comment: Hi, when I ran `toolchain pip install --upgrade KivyMD=master` I've got the following error: `ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'KivyMD=master'`

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced version in

**venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy_ios/recipes/sdl2_ttf/__init__.py**

```
version = "2.0.14"
```

to

```
version = "2.0.15"
```

And rebuild sdl2_ttf:

```
toolchain clean sdl2_ttf
toolchain build sdl2_ttf
```

Comment: Hi, did exactly what you suggested, but the problem remains. After modifying version in the __init__.py the `toolchain build sdl2_ttf` still builds the 2.0.14 version.